# Not able to destroy the prefab

Tags: c#, unity

In the code, everything is working smoothly, only problem I am facing is that the `Destroy(fuelprefabInstance)` is not getting Destroyed in `OnTriggerEnter` Method though the print statements are clearly executed and Destroy in `Spawn` method works fine as well. What am I missing?

Edit: It infact gives `NullReferenceException` if I try to set `fuelprefabInstance` to `false` instead of destroying the prefab using `fuelprefabintsnace.setActive(false);`

```
  public IEnumerator Spawn()
    {
        time1 = Random.Range (1, 5);
        spawning = true;
        timer = 0;
        initial = new Vector3 (Random.Range(rmin, rmax), 0.037f, Random.Range((-7.608864f + 10f),(r.renderer.bounds.max.z + 20)));
        fuelprefabInstance = (GameObject)Instantiate (fuelprefab, initial, transform.rotation);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (time1);
        spawning = false;
        Destroy (fuelprefabInstance, time1);  //this destroy works
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player") 
        {
            print("called");
           Destroy (fuelprefabInstance);     //this Doesnot
            print ("destroyed");
                }
    }
```

Comment: why downvote :/

Comment: Simran, this sounds like more of a debugging question. Have you attached the debugger and checked the state of `fuleprefabInstance`? Are you familiar with how to use the debugger?

Comment: @Byte56: No, I am not really familiar with using Debugger, would be glad to get some reference to that as well or anything that can help regarding the issue.As of now, It appears that fuelprefabinstance is null inside of OnTriggerEnter but nt able to figure out the reason

Comment: Likely because you're destroying it already at the end of the `Spawn()` method.

Comment: @Byte56:Not really, because it would not be visible if it was destroyed  before, It becomes invisible when it's destroyed and if the OnTriggerEvent is being triggered, I suppose that is not the possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the destroy function while you spawn and give it a try. Most likely the object gets destroyed before it even collides with the player. The prefab becomes null and throws the exception.

Comment: I tried doing that and it still did not work.

Comment: Is it getting instantiated properly ?

Comment: Yes, it does....

Comment: If you are going to reuse the prefab then you can disable it instead of destroying it. This will help save memory.

Comment: I have tried doing setActive to false but it gives nullreferenceexception for fuelprefabInstance